# Huffman codes generating fixed length encodings

Tags: huffman-code

Is it possible that the **Huffman codes** might generate fixed length encodings? If yes, under what condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible if the probabilities of all symbols of the alphabet are equal and the size of the alphabet is a power of 2.

[You can check it here](http://planetcalc.com/2481/).

Comment: Or you have two symbols with any non-zero frequencies. Or a power-of-two set of frequencies that are not equal, but close enough. E.g. 3 4 5 6.